# Array.prototype.fill com um objeto reusa a mesma instância em todos as posições do array

Tags: javascript, array

Necessito fazer um array multidimensional de tamanho variado, por exemplo 13 x 30.

Já consegui fazer, mas quando altero o valor de uma célula, ele altera de todos os itens daquele mesmo índice.

Já criei um array da seguinte forma:

```
const arr_teste = new Array(13).fill(new Array(30).fill(''));
```

O problema foi que quando alterei o valor de um item ele alterou de todos os demais, por exemplo:

```
arr_teste[1][1] = "Teste"
```

Resultou em:

```
(13) [Array(30), Array(30), Array(30), Array(30), Array(30), Array(30), Array(30), Array(30), Array(30), Array(30), Array(30), Array(30), Array(30)]
0
: 
(30) ['', 'Teste', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
1
: 
(30) ['', 'Teste', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
2
: 
(30) ['', 'Teste', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
3
: 
(30) ['', 'Teste', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
4
: 
(30) ['', 'Teste', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
5
: 
(30) ['', 'Teste', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
6
: 
(30) ['', 'Teste', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
7
: 
(30) ['', 'Teste', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
8
: 
(30) ['', 'Teste', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
9
: 
(30) ['', 'Teste', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
10
: 
(30) ['', 'Teste', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
11
: 
(30) ['', 'Teste', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
12
: 
(30) ['', 'Teste', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
length
: 
13
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

Como faço para alterar apenas 1 item do array multidimensional?

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a [documentação do método `fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#value):

> *all elements in the array will be this exact value: if `value` is an object, each slot in the array will reference that object*

Ou seja, todas as posições do array são preenchidas com exatamente o mesmo valor. E se o valor for um objeto, todos os elementos do array serão referências para aquele objeto.

E como em JavaScript, [arrays também são objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), isso quer dizer que todos os 13 elementos do array `arr_teste` apontam para o mesmo array de 30 elementos.

Indo por partes:

- `new Array(30).fill('')` cria um array com 30 elementos (sendo que todos eles são a string vazia)
- depois, este array com 30 elementos é passado para `new Array(13).fill`, ou seja, é criado um array com 13 elementos, sendo que todos os 13 são referências para o mesmo array de 30 elementos

Por isso que ao mudar um deles, todos acabam sendo alterados, pois no fundo todos eles apontam para o mesmo array.

A própria documentação [tem um exemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#using_fill_to_create_a_matrix_of_all_1) para contornar isso. Basta criar várias instâncias deste array de 30 elementos, uma para cada posição do `arr_teste`:

```js
const arr_teste = new Array(13);
for (let i = 0; i < arr_teste.length; i++) {
    // para cada posição do arr_teste, cria um novo array de 30 elementos
    arr_teste[i] = new Array(30).fill('');
}
// agora a alteração é feita somente no array da posição indicada
arr_teste[1][1] = "Teste";
```

Outra forma de fazer é usar `Array.from`, informando o tamanho e uma função de *callback* que retorna um novo array de 30 elementos a cada vez que é chamada:

```js
const arr_teste = Array.from({ length : 13 }, elem => new Array(30).fill(''));
// agora a alteração é feita somente no array da posição indicada
arr_teste[1][1] = "Teste";
```